# Can a class instance variable be excluded from a subclass in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, instance-variables

Possibly a dumb question, but pretend class Node has an instance variable called *strength*. And pretend class Episode, which extends Node, does not need *strength* (other subclasses do). Pretend also that there are a LOT of Episode nodes all storing an instance of *strength*. Is there any way in Java to say "this subclass does not have a *strength* variable"? I'm kind of seeing why this probably isn't allowed, but thought I'd check.

Update: Thanks all. As I suspected, the answer to this question is "no," but creating a subclass of Node with the variables/methods not needed by Episode, then connecting the other (sub)subclasses that need these variables/methods to that new subclass will do exactly what I want.

Comment: No, because by the Liskov Substitution Principle, a subclass has to do everything the superclass does.

Comment: No, there is not. You can make the variables inaccessible via encapsulation, but if there are so many subclasses that do not need a field of the superclass then your design is flawed.

Comment: Just leave `strength` out of `Node` then create a subclass that only adds `strength`. `Episode` can extend `Node` and your other classes that need `strength` can extend the newly created subclass. This way they will all have the parent `Node`...

Comment: @Turing85 Actually, one subclass that doesn't need the variable (but: a lot of instances of that subclass) and several other subclasses that do need it (with very few instances each). Thus, I have the annoying decision of storing irrelevant data in all the episodes or having the variable (and at least one method) cut from the superclass to a bunch of subclasses. Neither is particularly elegant, but I suppose I'm stuck with one of the two.

Comment: You can absolutely do this in Java, although it's usually (always) not a good idea.  It is not easy as you will have to create a custom classloader that modifies the class while being dynamically loaded, but to honestly answer your question: yes, it's possible.  Interesting read about adding code at runtime follows.  Removing code uses roughly the same procedure.  http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071777/design-patterns/add-dynamic-java-code-to-your-application.html  I didn't put this as an answer because the SO community is usually too closed-minded to think outside of the box.

Comment: * apologies.  That article in the previous comment DOES NOT cover the procedure explained.  For more information, the BCEL docs would be a good place to look http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You can have e.g. `Node` and `StrengthNode` classes, one without *strength* and one with it, then `Episode` class will extend `Node`, others will extend `StrengthNode`.

Also, take into account the [access control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) in Java, as if *strength* is a `private` variable in `Node`, it will not be accessible in `Episode` class directly (only using getter method), but it's instance will exist in memory anyway.

Comment: I used something like this (see brso05's answer directly to the question). I used a Node class without the stuff Episode does not need, then a subclass of node with the other stuff that the (sub)subclasses use. That is Node -> Episode plus Node -> subNode -> Input, Identity, Response, Decision, Goal, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well The only way i can think around this is if your problem with the size of the object your instance variable stores either you can initialize the parameter to null or you can serialize the object with specifiying your instance parameters to be transient and go with serialize it , deserialize it .

This was just a thought around that , cant think of anything closer.

if you specifically dont need exact inheritance you go around that with creating a custom factory and extract the member variable using reflection , that would work too.

Anyway thats my opinion.